# CopyFiles Based on modified date as Yesterday's date SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I am trying to copy files from one folder to another folder based on getdate()-1

ex: Folder1

```
1) Order112.xml Date Modified 04/10/2018
2) Order113.xml Date Modified 03/10/2018
3) Order012.xml Date Modified 03/10/2018
```

I would like to copy these files into another location before i process them using Data flow task. ex; Copying `2nd and 3rd file` only. How can i acheive this either by expression in `foreachLoop container` or with  script task

I have tried with user variable to move all .xml files. I am not much bothered about name of file, only     date modified

[image]

Any ideas to add an expression in Foreach loop or acheive it with script task.

Ps: There is no date in the filename.I should also be able to change variable to ex: getdate()-2

Answer (score 3):

To copy files based on the date that the file was last modified, you'll want to use a script task to copy these files.  The `FileInfo` class has a `LastWriteTime` property that can be used to check the date that the file was last modified.  The C# example below illustrates this using SSIS variables that hold the source and destination folder names, as well as another SSIS variable for the number of days from the current date.  I'm assuming that you're only interested in the day, as opposed to the time, that the file was modified, thus the `LastWriteTime` and date (current date minus the given number of days) are only in the date format.

```
DirectoryInfo sourceFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["User::SourceFolder"].Value.ToString());

string destFileName;
string sourceFileName;

int daysBehind = Convert.ToInt32(Dts.Variables["User::DaysFromToday"].Value);
string destFolder = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationFolder"].Value.ToString();

var allFiles = sourceFolder.EnumerateFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(path
    //make sure to use the Date property to omit times from the comparison
        => path.LastWriteTime.Date == DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(daysBehind)).ToList();
   foreach (FileInfo fi in sourceFolder.GetFiles())
    {

    sourceFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fi.ToString());
    destFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(destFolder, sourceFileName);
    System.IO.File.Copy(fi.FullName, destFileName, true);

   }
```

Comment: Do you mind to add complete script please, including name spaces, Apprecite that.

Comment: Outside of System, the only other namespaces you'll need are System.IO and System.Linq.  The code above can just go in the Main method of a Script Task and once you substitute the variable names with the names of your variables and check variables in the ReadOnlyVariables field you should be good to use this.